# how can i update specific data in firebase realtime data with xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to update a specific data in firebase, for example NickName in this picture:
 [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYaH0.png)

at this moment im updating a data with putAsync of a whole new instance of object this way:

```
public static async Task AddOrUpdateUserInfo()
        {
            await fbClient
              .Child("Users/")
              .Child(Settings.LastUserID)
              .PutAsync(new Accounts { Email = AuthService.auth.User.Email , NickName = Settings.Nick , Key = Settings.LastUserID });
        }
```

and i want to update only one data value

any advice?

Comment: 1. retrieve the object you want to update, 2. update the properties you want to change, 3. save the object

Comment: it makes me talk to the database twice, i prefere once

Answer (score 0):

Writes to the Firebase database are always path-based: you write a value to a path. Your current code writes an entire object to `/Users/$uid`, but you can also write to a lower level. So you can update just `/Users/$uid/NickName`.

The code for that would look something like:

```
await fbClient
  .Child("Users")
  .Child(Settings.LastUserID)
  .Child("NickName")
  .PutAsync(Settings.Nick);
```

Comment: i get that error:    Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: 'Exception occured while processing the request.
Url: https://mada-e71d2.firebaseio.com/Users/7MdBbrbHGUatJ3ZUtTsMULlL7gB3/NickName/.json?print=silent
Request Data: pp
Response: {
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."
}
'

Comment: Interesting. The regular Firebase SDKs take simple values too, but it looks like it's having an issue here. Can you try with a hard-coded value: `.PutAsync("test")`? If that doesn't work either, a `Patch` call should also work.

Comment: i tried putAsync("test") abd i get the same error. what do you mean patch call?

Comment: See https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/blob/master/Database/Query/FirebaseQuery.cs#L129-L140